# Making plots in Shinny as similar as FRED's graphs

Tags: r, shiny

I want to make time-series plots in shiny as similar as FRED's graphs, is it possible? Which library do you suggest me? Thanks in advance.

Example: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CORESTICKM159SFRBATL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwpPE.png)

I tried with highcharter library. This is my best result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pztn.png)

Comment: The chart is made with `highcharts`. But replicating the look of the FRED graphs requires some effort. I would suggest to build on one of the default themes shipped with `highcharter`.